# Changes to the model object not passing back to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I'm loading the model to view and display it just fine. Then I make the changes to one of the fields and send it back. According to the break-point, I'm hitting the right action method but the model that's passed in contains no changes.

I suspect that I've unbound controls in the view. I've tried both the below, same problem both times.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(bike => bike.Color)
<input type="text" value="@Model.Color" />
```

Am I not binding it correctly? How should I do this?

The controller being hit with break-point looks like this. Note that the bike that's passed in contains no changes according to the intellisense. If I make the change manually in VS, they are stored to the DB.

```
public ActionResult BikeStore(Bike bike)
{
  ...
  return RedirectToAction("Bikes");
}
```

The model is Code First generated.

```
public partial class Bike
{
  [Key]
  public Guid Id{get; set;}

  [Required]
  [StringLength(999)]
  public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

The submitting is done using this.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Submit", "BikeStore", "Home", @Model, null)
```

But if I do the following, it works, as in - the addition comes in to the controller. Not the actual contents of any of the controls on the page, though. So I'm very sure those are not bound and I can't figure out why or how to make them.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Submit", "BikeStore", "Home", new Bike
{
  Id = Model.Id,
  Color = Model.Color + "!"
}, null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit action is wrong. You're passing @Model but this will be the model as it is when the view is rendered. You should be using a form with a submit button. This will bind the user edited values to the model on post.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BikeStore", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
{
    // your inputs
    // ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

Comment: That hasn't resolved the issue entirely but it pushed me forward. The question asked has been answered, indeed, so I'm accepting it and +1 for simplicity. I've also asked another question in this regard.